How to handle Output[] artifacts in Kubeflow Pipelines for distributed Spark jobs?
I'm working on a distributed Spark job as a component in Kubeflow Pipelines (KFP). According to the Kubeflow documentation, input and output artifacts can be handled using the type annotations Input[] and Output[]. Typically, output artifacts are written to the local file system of the pod running the component, and then uploaded to a remote storage system by the KFP backend i.e., s3 in my case.
However, in the case of distributed Spark jobs, there are multiple Spark executors running across different pods. Since each Spark executor operates independently and doesn’t share a common local file system with the main driver pod, it seems impractical for each executor to write output artifacts to the local pod file system as expected by KFP.(Correct me if I am wrong)
Here are my specific concerns:

How can Output[] artifacts be handled in a distributed Spark job, where multiple executors are involved?
If executors are writing to a local file system, won't this cause issues due to the distributed nature of the job?
What is the best practice to aggregate or manage output artifacts in such cases, especially when using KFP’s Output[] mechanism?

Any insights or best practices on how to handle this scenario would be appreciated. Thank you!
